# Angular form reset after validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, forms, validation

I am using angular js for validation on form its working fine but after form is valid i am sending ajax request and resting it with jquery code, So my form still shows valid. Here is following js snippet:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('myController', function ($scope) {    

    $scope.clearForm = function (formId) {
        $(formId)[0].reset();
        console.log($scope.note['title'])
        //$scope.note['title'] = null;
    };

    $scope.submitForm = function () {
        if ($scope.noteForm.$valid) {
            alert("valid");
            //ajax request
            $scope.clearForm('#noteForm');
        }
    }
});
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yrun26L0/)

If i am setting blank value with `$scope.note['title'] = null;` it shows error after clearing.

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Lubtpmkj/)

How can i resolve this? what i want is after resting from should goes to initial state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than clearing form in jQuery, I'd prefer you to use `$setPristine()` method on `form` that will make form as `pristine` in angular way. Also you need to clear form fields just by doing `$scope.note = {}`.

**Code**

```
$scope.clearForm = function (formId) {
    $scope.noteForm.$setPristine(); //you should use setPristine that will make for pristine
    $scope.note = {}; //this will clear a form values.
};
```

[**Demo Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/yrun26L0/2/)